# Passing arguments to jQuery "load"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to set up a simple webpage.  I have header, content, and footer div's, like so:

```
<body>
    <div id="headerDiv"></div>
    <div id="contentDiv"></div>
    <div id="footerDiv"></div>
</body>
```

The header & footer are loaded once, and then then content div will be loaded with content based on mouse clicks in the header:

```
<script>
    $(() => {
        $("#headerDiv").load("components/header.html");
        $("#footerDiv").load("components/footer.html");

        loadContent(window.location.hash.substring(1));
    });

    loadContent = (page, args) => {
        window.location.hash = '#' + page;
        switch (page) {
            case 'home':
                $("#contentDiv").load("components/home.html");
            break;
            case 'page1':
                const { argument } = args || '';
                $("#contentDiv").load("components/page1.html?param=" + argument);
            break;
            case 'page2':
                $("#contentDiv").load("components/page2.html");
            break;
            case 'page3':
                $("#contentDiv").load("components/page4.html");
            break;
            default:
                $("#contentDiv").load("components/home.html");
        }
    }
</script>
```

The above code snippets are in my `index.html`.  As you can see, I'm trying to pass an argument to `page1.html`, but it isn't working.  If I do `console.log(window.location.href)` from `page1.html` remains "index.html"; no argument ever gets processed when I load page1.html.  How can I get the argument passed to `page1.html`?  Do I have to load a PHP or some other script rather than raw HTML?

EDIT:  `loadContent` is called from `header.html` like this:

```
<a href="#page1" onclick="loadContent('page1', {argument: 'airport'})">
```

The idea is that the second parameter is an arbitrary JS object.

TIA!

Comment: Remove the `{}` around `{ argument }` and your code will work, but note that you don't seem to be supplying anything to the `args` argument, which is a secondary issue

Comment: Sorry, should hav e added more context around ```args```... You're right in that I don't supply anything to args in ```index.html``` itself, but in the header menu links, I'll have code like ```<a href="#page1" onclick="loadContent('kpis', {kpi: 'sample-kpi'})">```.  The idea is for args to be a Javascript object that can hold whatever I want, which is why I use the curly braces.

Comment: Note that `const { argument } = args;` will assign `argument` to the `argument` property on `args`. Since you don't have one (you only have a `kpi` property), it will be undefined.

Comment: The URL will never change; you've essentially reinvented single page applications :).

Comment: Inspired by @HereticMonkey, I just made an ```arguments``` global object.  Now its accessible from whatever component I put in the content div.  Not exactly what I wanted, but OK.